# Why are/were Euribor rates consistently lower than ECB deposit facility rates since 2020?

Tags: short-rate, banking, interbank-rates

Why are unsecured term deposits in EUR yielding lower than a simple overnight deposit at the ECB ? Isn't it supposed to be the opposite ?

The 3 month Euribor just broke -0,50% a few days ago, why was it so low for so long ?

Source : https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=143.FM.M.U2.EUR.RT.MM.EURIBOR3MD_.HSTA

I assume there must a quota on the ECB deposit facility ? What stops eurozone banks from using the deposit facility to a greater extent if that isn't the case ?

Comment: The basis seems pretty small though. One possible reason is that not all institutions have access to the deposit facility.